# polars groupby on categorical produces nulls

Tags: python, python-polars

I ran into an issue with polars where after a groupby on a categorical variable the labels are null

```py
import polars as pl
scores = pl.DataFrame({
    'zone': ['North', 'North', 'South', 'South'],
    'score': [78, 39, 76, 56]
}).with_column(pl.col("zone").cast(pl.Categorical))

scores.groupby("zone").count()
```

This produces the output below with null values for the levels. Is this expected? If so, is there a fix? Note that this doesn't happen when `zone` is set to a string

[image]

Comment: What version of polars are you using? It produces the correct output for me on `0.15.14` - there were some cat-related fixes recently.

Comment: Works on 0.15.13 as well.

Comment: Updated to 0.15.13 (conda) and the result is now as expected. Thanks